# BIOS showing wrong hard drive capacity

Tags: hard-disk, raid

I'm having some hard drive trouble. I had two 3T SATA drives in a RAID1, separate from the boot disk, and after taking them out to fix something else and plugging them back in they're no longer working and appear to be missing their partitions. This is true for both drives, they're behaving identically.

When I check the BIOS, it sees them as having 4G capacity. That's also what I see in lsblk and testdisk, which says it won't work if disk capacity isn't correctly detected and GNU ddrescue didn't find anything to save either. According to the Seagate website there isn't a new firmware version available and nothing on the boot disk changed from when they were working to when they weren't.

```
~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   3.9G  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0   3.9G  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 256.2G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 247.8G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi

~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-142-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001
Serial Number:    Z1F3TP48
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 064db4f7e
Firmware Version: CC24
User Capacity:    137,438,952,960 bytes [137 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Jan 17 21:26:45 2023 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Log Directory failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Any ideas what I've done or how I can recover the data?

**Update:**

I have applied a BIOS update (thanks, @Artem S. Tashkinov and @Ardonit) and it's still detecting the drives as 4G instead of 3T. I also tried accessing one of the drives on a different computer with a USB enclosure and lsblk is seeing it as 4G there as well.

I've heard that these drives could have problems (thanks, @bib) and was about to replace them before all this but I'd really like to recover their data first. I guess setting up a mirrored RAID doesn't help if both disks freak out the same way at the same time.

**Update 2:**

My browser crashed and I lost my guest login cookie so hopefully this update works.

This was a software raid and I was using mdadm. Thanks @symcbean, I should have mentioned that.

A friend let me try the disk on their Windows laptop via the USB enclosure and it couldn't even see the drive besides some I/O errors in the system log. Nothing in disk manager.

I learned that [mdadm puts the raid superblocks in different places depending on its version](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats), so I tried assembling and examining with --metadata set from 0 to 1.2 and every time gave the no RAID superblock error

I also used [SeaTools bootable](https://www.seagate.com/manuals/software/seatools-bootable/introduction/) to try manually setting the drive capacity since hdparm didn't want to do it, but no dice there either.

```
~$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 8089950/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

(I know that's the get command, but set gave me the same thing)

```
~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb 
/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST3000DM001                             
    Serial Number:      Z1F3TP48
    Firmware Revision:  CC24    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:    8089950
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:        3950 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:        4142 MBytes (4 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Recommended acoustic management value: 254, current value: 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    unknown 119[7]
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            Device-initiated interface power management
            Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    210min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 210min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c50064db4f7e
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 064db4f7e
Integrity word not set (found 0x0000, expected 0x88a5)
```

Comment: Is there a BIOS update for this PC?

Comment: From wikipedia... `This particular drive model was reported to have unusually high failure rates`.

Comment: Was this hardware raid?

Comment: @symcbean not likely, because we see two devices in the OS (see lsblk output)

Comment: Just because that is what we are seeing that now doesn't mean that was how it was configured in the past. Generally disk drives don't exhibit symptoms like this - OTOH hardware RAID devices do weird things to disks.